# Instantiate arguments in Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic

Consider the PROLOG predicate f(list,integer) with flow model (i,o).

```
f([],0).
f([H|T],S):-
    f(T,S1),
    S1 is S-H.
```

Give the result of the evaluation f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],S)?Justify the answer.

I've seen that we get the error "Arguments are not sufficiently instantied" and that is because the value of S is not updated in the end(only when the list is empty). Is this a good justification?

Comment: You probably have two typos in your second clause, it should read `f([H|T], S):- f(T, S1), S is S1-H.` or `f([H|T], S1):- f(T, S), S1 is S-H.`

Comment: Where does the term "flow model" come from? Generally one say that the predicate suppports a "mode" (in this case, mode `(+,?)`: first argument is in, second argument is "out" or it can be set, in which case the predicate "verifies")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've seen that we get the error "Arguments are not sufficiently
> instantied" and that is because the value of S is not updated in the
> end(only when the list is empty). Is this a good justification?

If this code is supposed to fail, yes.

The correct wording is:

This predicate is called with an *unbound variable* on second position, either at the top or recursively vai `f(T,S1)` (where `S1` is fresh and thus unbound).

Then the arithmetic evaluation

`S1 is S-H.`

will have an unbound variable on the right-hand side of `is/2` and cannot proceed (i.e. it will throw).

But note that it works if you switch to "constraint satisfaction over finite domains":

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
true.
```

Then replacing `is/2` by `#=`:

```
f([],0).
f([H|T],S):-
    f(T,S1),
    S1 #= S-H.
```

yields a working program:

```
?-  f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],S).
S = 36.
```